# Laravel inertia return all posts with limited number on columns and adding the user from a belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, inertiajs

Using Laravel, inertia, vue I would like to return all Posts with only the necessary columns in my index but I would like to add the user from a belongsTo relationship

Here is what I tried

**Test one : adding user**

```
   return Inertia::render('Posts/Index', [
            'posts' => Post::with('user')->get()->all('id','abstract','created_at')
        ]);
```

This returns all posts including the user from relationship but all columns in post are returned

**Test 2 : filtering columns**

```
   return Inertia::render('Posts/Index', [
            'posts' => Post::all('id','abstract','created_at')
        ]);
```

This returns all posts with only columns id, abstract and created_at

```
Test 3: ordered with user


return Inertia::render('Posts/Index', [
    'posts' => Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with('user')->get()
]);
```

This returns all post ordered with user and all columns

My question is how to return all posts with only selected columns, ordering them and adding the user from the belongsTo relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Finally this was the solution but instead on a user object I just passed its name (which is what I really needed).

```
return Inertia::render('Posts/Index', [
   // 'posts' => Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with('user')->get()
   'posts'=>Post::select('id','title','abstract','created_at')
   ->addSelect([
       'user'=>User::select('name')
       ->whereColumn('id','posts.user_id')
```

and for passing several columns of the user

```
 return Inertia::render('Posts/Index', [
            // 'posts' => Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with('user')->get()
            'posts' => Post::select('id', 'title','abstract', 'created_at')
                ->addSelect([
                    'userfirstname' => User::select('firstname') ->whereColumn('id', 'posts.user_id'),
                    'userlastname' => User::select('familyname') ->whereColumn('id', 'posts.user_id')  
                ])
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get()
        ]);
   ])
   ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
   ->get()
]);
```